# TFS in Visual Studio 2012 under Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-8, azure-devops

I'm having trouble connecting to the hosted [Team Foundation Service](http://tfspreview.com/) using Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Upon my first connect, a window was opened prompting me for my username and password, however I was added to TFS with a different Live ID.  I've re-registered a new Live ID and now I can't get access to TFS.  When I try to do so, I get this error:

> TF31003

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://runtingsproper.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/solved-tf31003-error-when-trying-to.html

Answer (score 3):

If you log out from All Live accounts in your Browser's and then try logging into TFS again you should be prompted for the credentials and you can login with the account that has access to TFS Preview.

Comment: If that doesn't work, clearing cookies is sort of a big hammer to take, but it will definitely get you logged out of the TFS Service and Live.

Comment: Also, check to make sure your live ID (well, the wrong one at least) isn't bound to your windows login.

Answer (score 0):

I got the tf31003 error while trying to connect to a hosted TFS at https://mycompanyname.visualstudio.com/

I could access the site using my Live Id through Firefox but when trying to connect using VS 2010 I was getting that error.

The issue with my case was that VS2010 was trying to login using Internet Explorer which I was signed in under a different account. To solve this I opened Internet Explorer and logout from Hotmail/Live and went to the about URL and connected to the TFS instance, which connected successfully.

After that I went back to VS 2010 and tried to connect to the server again, this time I was shown the Login window where I was able to enter my login details. Once done my server was successfully added to the 'Team Server Foundation list' and was able to get the list of all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, except I am running VS2012 Update 2. This is overboard, but this is a thorough list of everything I did that eventually fixed it.

1. Ensured Visual Studio was not running
2. I opened Internet Explorer, pressed CTRL+SHFT+DEL, selected everything and clicked "Delete"
3. I opened Fiddler and navigated to "Tools > Clear WinINET Cache" and "Tools > Clear WinINET Cookies"
4. I opened the windows Credential Manager and removed all entries (including all Web Credentials, Windows Credentials, and Generic Credentials)
5. I disconnected my Microsofot account from my Windows account
6. Opened Visual Studio and connected to TFS, and it finally prompted me to login

Again, this is overboard, and not very surgical, but as I was in a hurry, so I decided to take the shotgun run, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the simplest solution I got was to delete just three cookies.
I found this recommendation in other post. It worked for me.

```
cookie:*@login.live.com/
cookie:*@visualstudio.com/
cookie:*@tfs.app.visualstudio.com/

To see the cookie files directly so to "Internet Options -> In the Browsing History Section Click "Settings" -> Click "View Files" -> They are all text files.
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error (**TF31003** / **TF30063**) when [setting up a new TFS Build Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx) on Windows Server 2012 because [Active Scripting was not enabled in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821529/175679).

[image]

In order to login - you must enable active scripting to see the login prompt below...

[image]

I actually discovered this after installing Visual Studio where the popup dialog specifically informs you of this required setting. Hopefully this will save sometime hours of lost time...

[image]