# VS Express 2013 for Web - Browser is security restricted or JavaScript is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I initially installed the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web on my desktop. My desktop runs Windows 8.1 with internet explorer 11. It ran fine until the license expired after the first 30 days. I tried to sign in to renew the license, however after clicking the 'sign in' button I get an error dialog. The dialog states 'Browser is security restricted or javaScript is disabled. I have no other option but to close and exit Visual Studio.

I went to the online forums for Microsoft. There were discussions and suggestions on how to fix the error. I tried lowering the settings for the security tab in internet explorer. I have validated the option for scripting is enabled. I have also added https://*.visualstudio.com to the trusted sites tab. Other users on the forum have tried the same suggestions and have not succeeded in signing into the visual studio application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is another issue people are running into that is a bug with the login dialog. The login dialog is using a Web Browser control to login the user. By default it loads up "about:blank" as the URI. It then proceeds to try to execute some JavaScript (just ";") to verify it has permissions to do so. On some machines this is problematic because "about:blank" has been mapped to zone 0, or the Local Machine zone. When the JavaScript is executed MSHTML will check the zone of the URI and then the policy for executing scripts. By default the Local Machine zone is locked down, and all script executions result in a Query policy. What this means is if you're running in immersion mode (aka in Internet Explorer) you will get a message box asking if you want to execute the script. However, the Web Browser control used by VS 2013's "Sign In" dialog doesn't run MSHTML code in immersion mode, so the Query policy effectively equates to a Disallow policy. The bug here is someone in VS assumed "about:blank" resolves to the Internet zone, and when it resolves to the Local Computer zone you get this behavior.

The workaround is to remove "about:blank" zone mapping. Point regedit to this key:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains]

Remove the "blank" key.

Alternatively you can change the Local Machine Lockdown policy for executing scripts. The reg key for that is:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Lockdown_Zones\0]

Set the "1400" DWORD value to 0.

Comment: The first option (the only option I tried) worked.  I was in the ballpark with what I was thinking.  But, you nailed the specifics.  Thanks for the legwork and response here.  This is the issue and solution.

Comment: ....Just saw your post on the ticket at Microsoft.  I posted a comment before I had seen it.  all credit is yours.

Comment: Did the blank key removal tip and could sign in. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 76):

I had exactly the same problem, here is what I did:

a) Go in IE, click on settings wheel then **Internet Options** and **Security tab**.

b) Click on **Custom level** button (make sure you select **Internet** zone).

c) In **Security Settings** window, under **Scripting** I set **Enabled** for **Active scripting**.

After that Sign In should work.  Even though Chrome is default browser, it seems that VS uses IE for sign in process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry but Active scripting is enabled.  I installed fiddler and it appears that the login url being used is being redirected and returns a 401 error. I am working with Microsoft to ascertain the correct action.

Comment: That doesn't work for me either. I also used the lowest possible security level, but it still can't sign in.

Comment: Not sure if it will any difference, I changed default browser from Chrome to IE and back during my testing, might be linked.

Comment: This worked for me. I have Chrome as my default browser, but changing that setting in IE fixed the issue. As an indicator that is was working, the Bing homepage didn't display an image until after I had changed this setting.

Comment: This worked for me while the accepted answer did not.

Comment: This worked for me; The accepted answer also did not, just like @stimms. I should add that I do not know why :-)

Comment: I'm another for whom this worked, whereas the accepted answer did not.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  When I tried to set it to "Prompt", it still wouldn't work, so I had to set it to "Enabled".

Comment: After enabling 'Active Scripting' I was facing the error *'SP324098: Your browser could not complete the operation'* . To fix this I had to check 'Always allow session cookies' in 'Internet Options -> Privacy (tab) -> Settings -> Advance'.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites you need to list in your Trusted Sites.  Following the trace of what the stupid, stupid login script does:

https://*.visualstudio.com
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com
https://*.accesscontrol.windows.net
https://auth.gfx.ms
https://login.live.com

Only then was I able to log on to my FREE software.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is Albert from Microsoft. Just want to let you all know that this issue has been fixed in the upcoming Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013. Thanks for your patience while we figured this one out :)

Comment: On the one hand, this isn't an answer and should be a comment. On the other hand, if this is real, then that's pretty cool.

Comment: Nope. The same issue exists in VS2017 Community, dear Microsoft.  Even though Chrome is the default browser, I had to enable Security->Internet->Scripting->Active Scripting "Enable" in IE 11.  I will likely have to do this again because IE security policy is controlled by troglodytes in this specific environment.  Hence, Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem **"Browser is security restricted or JavaScript is disabled"** here but the solution from #jic didn't work for me..

If you can and it is **convenient** for you this is a solution which worked for me:

I have created a new user/profile on my PC and for this user it was just working fine.

Before this action I have tried to make an user account which had this problem as:

1. Power user - didn't work
2. Administrator - didn't work as well

So the last solution in my case was a **brand new user** on the PC..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

Open Control Panel, Internet Options.

First, I clicked the Security tab and turned security the security for the Internet zone to its minimum.

Next, click the Privacy tab, then click Advanced.  Choose "Accept" for both types of cookies.

Of course you can change these all back after extending your VS trial.

Answer (score 0):

you must change secure settings of iexplore for admin account. If logon by other account, you must start iexplore under admin account or logon under admin account, because you will get license after admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start --> Run --> type cmd and click on OK.

Command Prompt will be opened. Then enter this command.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now try to access https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/Profile/View

It worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

As I can not add a comment yet to the answer of CBGraham, I've to add this note over here:
The solution described from CBGraham worked for me (Thanks Graham). I had to add an additional link:
https://account.live.com

Then I opened the IE and tried to login to a Microsoft site. I left the IE window open and just clicked once again on the VS to login. Then it worked for me. Even with strong restrictions on the IE settings. While I'm surprised why someone should set down his security settings, just to register VS.